# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable is shown even when I explicitly declare it as a dictionary

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer, typeerror

```
def format_duration(num):
    if num!=0:
        l=[0,0,0,0,0]
        d={10:"year",11:"day",12:"hour",13:"minute",14:"second",20:"years",21:"days",22:"hours",23:"minutes",24:"seconds"}
        n=num
        j=[]
        if n>0:
            s=num%60
            l[4]=s
            mi=int(num/60)
            l[3]=mi
            if mi>=60:
                m=mi%60
                l[3]=m
                hi=int(mi/60)
                l[2]=hi
                if hi>=24:
                    h=hi%24
                    l[2]=h
                    di=int(hi/24)
                    l[1]=di
                    if di>=365:
                        d=di%365
                        l[1]=d
                        y=int(di/365)
                        l[0]=y
        for i in range(5):
            if l[i]!=0:
                if l[i]==1:
                    j.append("1"+" "+d[int("1"+str(i))])
                else:
                    j.append(str(l[i])+" "+d[int("2"+str(i))])
        if len(j)>1:
            return ", ".join(j[0:-1])+" and "+j[-1]
        else:
            return j[0]
    else:
        return "now"
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/workspace/default/src/codewars-test/codewars_test/test_framework.py", line 111, in wrapper
        func()
      File "tests.py", line 14, in basic
        test.assert_equals(format_duration(132030240), "4 years, 68 days, 3 hours and 4 minutes")
      File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 32, in format_duration
        j.append(str(l[i])+" "+d[int("2"+str(i))])
    **TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**
```

Comment: ``d=di%365`` assigns an integer to ``d``. You likely meant ``di %= 365`` instead, but generally this error could be avoided by using descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the problematic line is `d = di % 365`, which re-assigns an `int` to `d`.  In addition to more descriptive variable names, I'll suggest that using static typechecking (e.g. [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) makes it very easy to discover typos like this:

```
>mypy test.py
test.py:23: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "Dict[int, str]")
test.py:24: error: No overload variant of "__setitem__" of "list" matches argument types "int", "Dict[int, str]"
test.py:24: note: Possible overload variants:
test.py:24: note:     def __setitem__(self, SupportsIndex, int) -> None
test.py:24: note:     def __setitem__(self, slice, Iterable[int]) -> None
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The `Incompatible types ...` error is from this line, where you assign an `int` to `d` (which was initialized as a `Dict[int, str]`):

```
                        d=di%365
```

and the `No overload variant ...` is letting you know that here, you're trying to assign `d` to a list `l` that was declared as containing only `int`s (i.e. you probably meant to use `di` here as well):

```
                        l[1]=d
```